# Find change in a column with date column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I got after melting and filtering based on some criteria, it looks like this

```
 P       D
 A   2018-01-01
 A   2018-01-02
 A   2018-01-03
 B   2018-01-03
 A   2018-01-04
 B   2018-01-04
 A   2018-01-05
 A   2018-01-06
 A   2018-01-07
 B   2018-01-07
```

From this dataframe, I want to make some dataframe like this,

```
P        D1          D2
A     2018-01-01  2018-01-02
A, B  2018-01-03  2018-01-04
A     2018-01-05  2018-01-06
A, B  2018-01-07      -
```

From the column `P` in data, we can see that there is only a value `A` from `2018-01-01` to `2018-01-02`, hence we will have the first row in the result dataframe as `A, 2018-01-01, 2018-01-02`

Similarly, there is A and B from `2018-01-03` to `2018-01-04` hence the second row in the dataframe.

How to perform this in pandas efficiently.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like the below:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

#generate dataframe
letters = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B']
dates = [dt.date(2018,1,1), dt.date(2018,1,2), dt.date(2018,1,3), dt.date(2018,1,3), dt.date(2018,1,4), dt.date(2018,1,4), dt.date(2018,1,5), dt.date(2018,1,6), dt.date(2018,1,7), dt.date(2018,1,7)]
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(letters, dates), columns = ['P','D'])
```

[image]

```
#generate date pairs
start_date = df.iloc[0]['D']
end_date = df.iloc[-1]['D']
dates = [start_date + dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end_date-start_date).days, 2)]
date_pairs = zip(dates, [date + dt.timedelta(days=1) for date in dates])

#generate output dataframe
l = []
for date1,date2 in date_pairs:
    p = df[(df['D'] >= date1) & (df['D'] <= date2)]['P'].unique()
    l.append({'P' : p, 'D1' : date1, 'D2' : date2})

out = pd.DataFrame(l)[['P','D1','D2']]
out
```

output:

[image]

Of course, if you have an odd number of dates (as in your example), the last date will not be caught, but that can be appended at the end if desired.

Answer (score 0):

I have made an ad-hoc solution which I know is not optimal at all. Hope someone can suggest some improvements and enhancements for the same.

```
a_df = pd.read_clipboard()
s = a_df.groupby(by=['D'])['P'].unique().apply('+'.join).reset_index()

s['s_1'] = s.P.eq(s.P.shift(-1))
s['s_2'] = s.P.eq(s.P.shift(1))

a1 = s.loc[(s['s_1'] == True) & (s['s_2'] == False)].index.values
a2 = s.loc[(s['s_1'] == False) & (s['s_2'] == True)].index.values

count = 1
s['Flag'] = 0
for x,y in zip(a1, a2):
    s.loc[x:y, 'Flag'] = count
    count += 1

s.groupby(['Flag'], as_index=False).agg({'P' : 'first', 'D' : ['min', 'max']}).sort_values([('D', 'min')])

    Flag    P   D
        first   min     max
1   1   A   2018-01-01  2018-01-02
2   2   A+B     2018-01-03  2018-01-04
3   3   A   2018-01-05  2018-01-06
0   0   A+B     2018-01-07  2018-01-07
```